# How to get All facebook photos from FQL

Tags: php, facebook, limit, facebook-fql

I am using `FQL` to collect all Facebook photos for the application also i have 533 photos on facebook but the issue is that this `query` will return only 400 records.

FQL QUERY

```
SELECT src_big,target_id FROM photo WHERE pid IN
(SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject='".$session_fbuserid."') OR
pid IN (
    SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid IN
        (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner='".$session_fbuserid."' AND type!='profile')
)
```

My Facebook Album

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `limit 1000` to the end of your query.

```
SELECT src_big,target_id FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject='".$session_fbuserid."') OR pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner='".$session_fbuserid."' AND type!='profile')) LIMIT 1000
```